# Error in Login Form. IF condition is not working properly

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2013

This is my Code behind
 **Login Button**

```
 dall login = new dall();
            DataTable dt = login.select(("select ID,Password from Login"));
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (txtID.Text==dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() && txtPass.Text==dt.Rows[i][1].ToString())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully", "Login ALert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

                else
              {

                 MessageBox.Show("Login Failed", "Login Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
               }
```

And this is my code of connection class

```
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn);
            SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adptr.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
            return dt;
```

Comment: before the if statement do Trace.Writeline(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());and the same for the second one. Watch what comes out in the debug window.

Comment: You are all doing it wrong way fetch the data only for matching user name and password if value comes up from database then make it successful otherwise show failure.

Comment: Passwords should be stored encrypted too.

Comment: Probably your need to read something about [WHERE clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Yes you are right but I think he is trying to learn so he should start with basics to how to approach correctly and then get with encryption stuff.

Comment: After Debugging: 
dt.Rows[i][0] "1         " object {string}
dt.Rows[i][1] "Taimur                                  " object {string}
Values are correct...

Comment: @coder Yes I'm trying to learn

Comment: See the answer and try to do that.

Comment: I don't know the code for your answer :/

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that not working properly means failure message is is showing up the multiple times.

You are doing it wrong way the authentication. You can pull the data from the  database if the `ID` and `Password` matches and if records or value come from database then show success otherwise failure.

1) Change your query to use the parameters ID and Password.

```
 string query = "select ID,Password from Login Where ID = @ID AND Password =@Pssword"
```

2) Then add the parameters value to the sqlcommand

```
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.String);
```

3) Then check if `DataTable` has the value in it

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    //Show failure message
else
   //show success message
```

Comment: I have done same thing in another program. It works fine. But @Coder is right. It shows Multiple Times Failure.

Comment: Your sqlcommand is going to need parameters using this approach or it won't work. and assign values.

Comment: Error1 'System.Data.SqlDbType' does not contain a definition for 'String'

Comment: Additional information: The parameterized query '(@ID int,@Password nvarchar(4000))select ID,Password from Login ' expects the parameter '@ID', which was not supplied